# How to control player move by pressing buttons on iOS screen?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project, and I can control my player through directionkeys on keyboard.I use the following code to decide the amount of movement:

```
moveInputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
```

For the method **GetAxisRaw**'s return value,  the doc said:

> The value will be in the range -1...1 for keyboard and joystick input.

I want to control the player when the game is running on iOS device, so I've drawn some buttons on the screen.

```
    GUI.Button(new Rect(80 - _offset.x / _guiScaleFactor, 180 - _offset.y / _guiScaleFactor, 40, 40), "U");
    GUI.Button(new Rect(80 - _offset.x / _guiScaleFactor, 260 - _offset.y / _guiScaleFactor, 40, 40), "D");
    GUI.Button(new Rect(40 - _offset.x / _guiScaleFactor, 220 - _offset.y / _guiScaleFactor, 40, 40), "L");
    GUI.Button(new Rect(120 - _offset.x / _guiScaleFactor, 220 - _offset.y / _guiScaleFactor, 40, 40), "R");
```

but I can't find a way to return a relative value in the range -1...1 by pressing buttons.

Could someone give me some pointers?

Comment: Could you include the code showing what you've done so far please.

Comment: Maybe missing the code about buttons? I think the rest code is not related to this question.

Comment: There are a lot of plugins on the asset store which already do this.  This one is free and maybe you can study how they did it: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15233